# Python: select logical code blocks with VIM

Tags: vim, python, selection

How does one select logically indented code blocks with VIM? For instance, consider this bit of Python:

```
01:class Foo(object):
02: 
03:    def __init__(self, bar):
04:
05:        if 'baz' in bar:
06:            print("I love baz!")
07:
08:            print("You made the best choice!")
09:
10:        elif 'boo' in bar:
11:            print("I like boo!")
12:
13:        else:
14:            print("I like your choice!")
15:
16:        self.choice = bar
17:        self.someList = []
18:
19:        print("Foo sucessfully created!")
20:
21:
22:    def bim(self):
23:        print("Bam boo")
24:        return True
```

How can I select all the lines of common indentation? That is, if I'm on line 06, it would select lines 06-08 (inclusive)? Or if I'm on line 16, it would select lines 05-19.

How can I select all the lines of common indentation and additionally the line which 'initializes' it? That is, if I'm on line 06, it would select lines 05-08 (inclusive)? Or if I'm on line 16, it would select lines 03-19.

How can I easily add to the selection the upper-level indentation? That is, if I've got the `__init__` method selected, how would I then transition to having the entire class selected?

This question encompasses the general case of many other (often unanswered) VIM/Python questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579723/whats-the-fastest-way-to-select-a-function-of-python-via-vim). My initial inclination was to put a bounty on that question, but I would actually prefer to know this more general case, which would help users in that situation and in other situations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [vim-indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) plugin, which defines a new text object based on indentation levels. It provides the following mappings (taken from documentation):

```
    Key Mapping       Description

    <count>ai         (A)n (I)ndentation level and line above.
    <count>ii         (I)nner (I)ndentation level (no line above).
    <count>aI         (A)n (I)ndentation level and lines above/below.
    <count>iI         (I)nner (I)ndentation level (no lines above/below).
```

Therefore:

- Press `vii` to select all the lines of common indentation
- Press `vai` to select all the lines of common indentation and additionally the line which 'initializes' it

Note that after selecting an indentation level you can go further by pressing `ii` or `ai` again. For example, if you are on line 06 and press `vai`, lines 05-08 are selected. If you press `ai` again, you get the whole `__init__()` selected (i.e. lines 03-19). Pressing `ai` once again will select the entire class.

Comment: Thank you very very much! This is terrific, yet so simple to use.